# How do I increment section by 0.1 and subsection by 0.0.1?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

This is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{extbook} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{titling} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\newcommand{\atoc}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{#1\par}} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\begin{document}
\chapter{helo}   
\section{first}   
\subsection{first sub}   
\section{second} 
\end{document}
```

It produces

[image: output]

How do I increment the section number by 0.1, and the subsection number by 0.0.1?

I want this to look like

> **1.1 first**
>
> **1.1.1 first sub**
>
> ....

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! As a general rule here, we want you to show your preamble, because it affects what your output looks like. The style you say you want is actually the default `book` class style for chapters and sections, so without your preamble, we can't tell why you're getting a different style. If you delete unnecessary packages and commands in your preamble, one by one, then you may be able to identify the source of the unwanted style, and restore it to the default. (If `\titleformat` appears in your preamble, it may be the culprit.)

Comment: Identical to: [How do I increment section by 0.1 and subsection by 0.0.1?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694440/how-do-i-increment-section-by-0-1-and-subsection-by-0-0-1)

Comment: Voting to close this, since it's the same as your other question. You've been asked to show complete code that creates the problems you're having, yet you haven't. People will be happy to help you, but you need to help us by showing *exactly* what you're doing. So saying "preamble and packages defined in another file" is exactly NOT showing us what you're doing.

Comment: @Alan Munn I would not like to post my 100+ line document here with personal information. If I was going to edit it, it would take a long time. If it helps, I did create a book class.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum so Im still learning things. Latex is also something I picked up a few weeks ago so please do be patient with me. Thanks :)

Comment: @AshwinFernandez please edit your clarification (i.e. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694444/how-do-i-increment-section-by-0-1-and-subsection-by-0-0-1#comment1723647_694444) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694444/how-do-i-increment-section-by-0-1-and-subsection-by-0-0-1#comment1723648_694444) into the question body itself. Thanks. // The simplest answer to your question is to `\renewcommand`  `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` appropriately, but a better answer would be to use the `titlesec` package's formatting capabilities.

Comment: @WillieWong I don't know how to move it into body, could you please help me? How will I use titlesec?

Comment: What Willie means is that you should click "Edit" and include your preamble in the question, rather than posting it in the comments. By the way, editing will boost the visibility of your post—in the future, please edit rather than reposting due to low activity.

Comment: The expected result is nothing else than the *default* one as long as you use the standard `book` class (or `extbook`, but why ?), and provided you don't use the `\frontmatter` directive. Hence you don't need neither `titling` nor `titlesec`, and the `\thesection` doesn't need to refefined. The "default" definition would be `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}`

Comment: @AshwinFernandez: All you need to do is remove the `\renewcommand{\thesection}` that you currently have. Once that's removed, the sectional units will be appropriately incremented and printed.